# looking for a method that will show tomorrow's date in ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, time

*Though, I already got the answer to my question, I decided to edit it.*

I was looking for any method in Ruby that can show tomorrow's date.
It's ok if it will show the time as well, I will format its output.

The **Time.now** gives current date, time and timezone:

```
Time.now
=> 2013-06-11 13:09:02 +0900
```

How can I use this method to get a date for tomorrow?

It's ok if there are other methods that can do it.

Comment: Your question is misleading/not clear. At the beginning, it sounds like you are looking for a date (without time), but at the end, it looks like you are looking for a way to add exactly 24 hours to a time.

Comment: Oscar, this sort of comment is unproductive, and shows you don't understand how Stack Overflow works. If you ask a good question, and provide the information needed, you'll get up-votes. Fail to do that and you'll get down-votes. But, why do you care? Shouldn't getting an answer be more important than getting points which mean very little?

Comment: Ruby's Date class has the [`+` operator](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2B), used to add values to a Date object. The first example is: `Date.new(2001,2,3) + 1    #=> #<Date: 2001-02-04 ...>`.

Comment: @oscar I didn't waste time downvoting. It is done in an instance. I may have wasted time reading your question, though. By the way, you accepted an answer that uses a Rails method even though you explicitly mentioned in the question that you are not using Rails lol. That adds another reason why your question is not clear.

Comment: @oscar, while each user is certainly welcome to voice his/herself, you might want to consider that some users are vastly more experienced with SO than the majority of others. With 40K+ rep points, the Tin Man is indeed in a very good position to understand what you meant, and I don't think it behooves new users like yourselves to denigrate the perspective of top users. Quite frankly, you'd probably have a more productive experience if you followed their advice.

Comment: All, I've updated the post though it is already solved and closed. Let me know if it's still not clear. I like things to be perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @sawaさん、よろしくお願いします :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
require 'date'

tomorrow = Date.today + 1
```

`tomorrow` is a date object. You can print it in the format you want.

Comment: This is the correct answer. First, it is a pure Ruby solution. Second, it returns a `Date` object, which is precisely what is asked for in the original post.

Comment: Also you can write `tomorrow = 1.days.from_now`, but this is Rails

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Time.now + 24*60*60
```

*(Edited: xaxxon is right.  My earlier version used Rails' functionality)*

Comment: 1.day isn't ruby.  `ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > 1.day
NoMethodError: undefined method `day' for 1:Fixnum`   from question: Please note, I don't mean about Rails, this is about Ruby.  Not in 2.0, so I'm not sure what "earlier version" you're referring to: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Fixnum.html

Comment: @Stu Gla, thank you anyway. Because, what you answered worked for me.

Comment: A day isn't always 24*60*60 seconds long.  Due to daylight savings, you can sometimes remain in the same day, or advance two days forward.

Answer (score 3):

## ruby 2.6+ helper method

```
Date.tomorrow
```

Comment: this requires Rails

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Stu Gla:

```
today = Time.now
tomorrow = today + (60 * 60 * 24)
```

you can then use the .strftime method to format... example:

```
puts tomorrow.strftime("%F")
# => 2014-08-07
```

Comment: A day isn't always 24*60*60 seconds long. Due to daylight savings, you can sometimes remain in the same day, or advance two days forward.